# C# .Net Compact Framework 3.5 FtpWebRequest Windows Mobile 6

Tags: c#, ftp, windows-mobile, compact-framework, ftpwebrequest

I need help with my code.

I want to Upload a File in a FTP Server but i get an Exception (NotSupportedException)

at this line: `FtpWebRequest result = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);`

I changed the WebRequest with FtpWebRequest too but the exception is still there.

I checked this out with a messagebox my URI is correct:

`ftp://192.168.178.20/FOLDER/FILE10.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`WebRequest` does not support ftp on the compact framework (hence the `NotSupportedException`), and the `FtpWebRequest` class is unavailable (you shouldn't even be able to compile if you attempt to use it).

There is a library available at https://ftp.codeplex.com/.

Comment: i will test it ty, with the ComponentPro Ftp Framework i got an typeloadexception on my mobile but with the simulator it works..